# MembershipProvider Class include reference in Class Project

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im creating a new MemebershipProvider class. but in my project MemebershipProvider class isn't in the references so i had a look for System.Web.Security to include in my project there wasn't one so i included the reference System.Web but i still get no reference to the MembershipProvider class does anyone know what i must do to include MembershipProvider class reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Web.ApplicationServices
```